# Getting all the accounts with at least 3 projects

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all the accounts who have at least 3 projects.

I decided to start from the link table:

```
SELECT   
        accounts_project_1accounts_ida
FROM    accounts_project_1_c 

GROUP BY accounts_project_1accounts_ida
HAVING   COUNT(accounts_project_1accounts_ida) > 3
```

But it returns all the table, even the accounts with only one project.

For example, this query only returns 1 result:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts_project_1_c` WHERE `accounts_project_1accounts_ida` LIKE '25490fce-5354-d1a2-fbe7-541b6c5b57d0'
```

Here is the table structure:

[image]

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: tried HAVING COUNT(*) ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HAVING clause is not correct. It should be

```
HAVING COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) > 3
```

From you schema, I understand that each project has an id, `accounts_project_1project_idb` and an account associated with it. The account's id is the `accounts_project_1accounts_ida`. So you need to group by your record by the account's id and then pick all of them which have at least three projects (three records in your table). That being said, I think if you change your HAVING clause to the one above, you will get that you want.

```
SELECT   
        accounts_project_1accounts_ida,
        COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb)
FROM    accounts_project_1_c 

GROUP BY accounts_project_1accounts_ida
HAVING COUNT(accounts_project_1project_idb) > 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, one account has one id accounts_project_1accounts_ida, one project has one id accounts_project_1project_idb, and one accounts can have several projects. Nevertheless, changing the HAVING clause doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Vico you are welcome. Please see my updated post. I missed to include the aggregate to the select statement :(.

Comment: I was about to say: It's not working!
But I think it's a PhpMyAdmin issue, it says 3716 results, but only displays 150...

So I guess it's solved! Thanks a lot.